# Bootstrap progress bar in Rails based on db fields

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap progress bar in my rails app, based on the value in a database field.
On my show page for user I put:

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" 
 aria-valuenow="<% @user.level %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"   style="width: <% @user.level %>">
```

But it doesn't work - width attribute wants to have a percent '%' sign. How to go around it?

Answer (score 0):

Customize ruby code and add '%'

```html
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" 
 aria-valuenow="<%= @user.level %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"   style="width: <%= "#{@user.level}%" %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what output you get from `user.level` but if it is the css you are having problems with, just add your unit `%`, `px` or `em`:

```
style="width: <%= @user.level %>%"
```

Comment: you also need to use `<%=`, not `<%`